# Github: Automerge immediately after a push and only for selected branches

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I'd like to enable auto merge ONLY for `dev`->`staging` (i.e. merged from `dev` to `staging` branch) and immediately after someone pushes anything to `dev`. Because merges come from PR, this PR should also be automatically created. The solution should not require additional CI/CD software (e.g. Teamcity), but I'm OK to write some scripts, and should be integrated into Github.

So the process is: someone manually merges his feature branch into the `dev` branch. This is automatically captured and immediately a PR from `dev` to `staging` is created, some tests are run, and if all tests pass then the merge occurs automatically.

I looked at `auto-merge` in Github but it's too simple for my use case. I'm thinking about using Github Action but wondering if anyone has done something similar? Thanks!

BTW I'm OK if the second step (PR) has to be manually triggered, but I cannot use `auto-merge` for just one branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The solution should not require additional CI/CD software (e.g. Teamcity), but I'm OK to write some scripts, and should be integrated into Github.

That kind of integration is called [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) and will use a [workflow file](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/about-workflows) that you put in your GitHub repository.

You can therefore adapt [`vsoch/pull-request-action`](https://github.com/vsoch/pull-request-action), which can open a pull request to master branch (or otherwise specified) whenever a branch with some prefix is pushed to.
While it is not exactly your use case, you can fork that GitHub Action to make to do exactly what you need.